# Socket.IO Rooms on different servers

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

**My goal**

I want to create a game with different playing rooms. Playing rooms are not connected in any kind. Only the one thing: I need to be able to move a player to other room.

**My thought**

There will be many users playing, so it will be a good thing to use many servers and many node-instances at each server.

**I use**

NodeJS with SocketIO. Playing rooms are SocketIO rooms. Each player is connected to only one room.

**Question**

But what I should do, if I need to move a user from one room at server #1 to another room at server #2?

**Methods I know**

I have found methods to have connection between servers by NoSQL as Redis. I can send events like this to other rooms.

But it seems to be better thing, I will send command to my client: "disconnect from server #1, connect to server #2, to room ..." (and store all possible rooms in redis client). So, it will be direct connection, not the "server #1 -> redis -> server #2". I want it to be fast.

**Main question**

Is there a way to transfer client connection from one server to another, fast and simple? Or may be use Redis pub-sub is not so bad by speed and it's ok to use it? What is the best solution?

Thank you.

Comment: In the future, try to focus your posts more precisely on specific questions. A question about how to transfer clients from one Socket.IO server to another could be very interesting.  However, this question isn't just about that, it's also about Redis performance, and any other possible solutions to your general problem. That's too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JeremyBanks May be I wasn't clear, because of the language (and stress), but the question is more about the best practice on working with many clients. Redis is one way. Connecting directly to different servers (with commands like "connect to other server") - is the second one. I had just gave examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is ok.
It's pretty fast and easy to use.